# Is it possible to use source maps to generate a usable stacktrace (with Crashlytics for example) with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, crashlytics, source-maps

I use Crashlytics to monitor crashes in my application, including JavaScript errors. But in release, the stack trace that I return is unusable (only info on bundle.js).

This is for a NativeScript application. Currently I catch JS errors to send them in Crashlytics, but the errors are like that (because I use --bundle --env.uglify) :

```
at e.crash (file:///data/data/com.appwhite.android/files/app/bundle.js:1:36166)
at Object.handleEvent (file:///data/data/com.appwhite.android/files/app/bundle.js:1:39772)
at handleEvent (file:///data/data/com.appwhite.android/files/app/vendor.js:1:221997)
```

I would like to have a stack trace readable with the original files :

```
at HomeComponent.crash (file:///data/data/com.appwhite.android/files/app/app/main/home/home.component.js:99:16)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.ngfactory.js:13:27)
at handleEvent (file:///data/data/com.appwhite.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:21694:45)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this thread: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/pull/854#issuecomment-490090453

In short, you could use `--env.hiddenSourceMap` and generate external source maps somewhere outside your native application in order to avoid increasing the app size because of the source maps. Then, you could use these hidden source maps and convert the stack trace using tools like https://sourcemaps.info/